# MySql filtering and grouping

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble filtering data out a relational table.   The query is part of a join, but I am stuck on a basic part.

I need to remove all the results with a certain id if the condition is found.

query similar to:

select * from colors where color != 'red' group by id

> ```
> id  color
> 1   red
> 1   blue
> 1   blue
> 2   green
> 2   blue
> 3   green
> 3   orange
> 4    red
> 5    white
> ```

returns 1,2,3,5

I need it to only return 2,3,5

I am not sure what mysql command to use

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from colors group by id having not group_concat(color) LIKE "%red%"
```

should work (not tested).

But it's weird to have many ids with same value...

Comment: select group_concat(color) as colors group by id having not colors like '%red%'

Comment: It's anyway a bad way, I think it should be a join table but I don't know your database schema.

Comment: Or something like that.   The multiple ids is wierd, but it is how the data is related from another table.

Comment: Yea there is a join in the sql and other where clauses, but I didn't need to get into all that for this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM my_table
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM my_table
   WHERE color = ?
)
```